# How to generate new files from a list in bash

Tags: bash, files

I have a list of hostnames and I need to create new files based on those hostnames. So, for example, I have a list of 10 hostnames, but I need each of these hostnames in the list to have new files created with the files names being the hostname it's created for. These hostnames are not sequential, i.e. hostname1, hostname2, etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an emtpy file, you can use `touch`. Use `xargs` to read a file and run a command on each line.

```
xargs touch < list
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. One further question: if I wanted the files outputted to be sent to another directory from the originating file, how can that be done?

Comment: To ask a new question, ask a new question. Also, please provide more details (sample input, expected outcome) so we can test the solution.

Comment: You could wrap it in a subshell `(cd path/to/dir && xargs touch) < list` maybe?